# Method not being called after invoke delay (unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delay, invoke

I'm trying to create a apply a fairly simple buff to my character for a short duration, but it seems that whatever method I try to use it does not want to apply.

I've tried creating a manual timer, making use of coroutine and now making use of invoke with a delay, but in each case it applies the increase in speed on collision, but then never does anything after the delay (also doesn't debug log after delay), see the screenshot below for the code.

[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV4Jo.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You destroy the gameobject allong with the script, that's why it never get's executed.

I'm not sure why you destroy the gameobject but you can remove the `Destroy(this.gameObject);`

If the `Destory()` method is necessary, you can use it inside your `TimerBuff()` method like this.

```
public void TimerBuff()
{
    Debug.Log("timerstop");
    PlayerMovement.runSpeed = 5f;
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```